# Trouble agreeing on the following basic contract terms

Tags: negotiation, contracts, contractors

Working with a company as an independent contractor. What would be a relatively bulletproof way of meeting the two following conditions in the agreement?

1. Contractor is free to work onsite or offsite at times of his choosing
2. In the event something breaks in the company system, contractor is responsible for resolving the issues asap (and some reasonable time frame here)

Note: client is suggesting 'issues should be addressed within 30 minutes', which is unreasonable, however, I am having trouble wording a sensible solution with a reasonable time frame.

I appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I were making such an agreement a 'reasonable' time frame is closer to 4 hours.  If you are operating solo, however, there are times you simply can't be there for at least a day or so.  They need to set up a contingency clause so that if you can't be there they can call in a backup provider - someone both of you should know in advance.

Comment: Yes because all new independent contractors can afford attorneys that charge thousands of dollars to review a document.

Comment: @FreshyFresh ...because all independent contracts can afford to be screwed by improperly forged contracts?

Answer (score 6):

You need -- for the second part -- language of a "service level agreement".  It will go into detail as to what you're on the hook for and what you're not.  Don't leave this up to a few words and a handshake.  It's all great -- until the event happens, and it's not clear what should be going on.

Try this for starters:

http://www.biztree.com/Templates/Service-Level-Agreement.html

Answer (score 1):

Everything is negotiable in a contract. There is absolutely no "bulletproof" way of getting your requests, because each potential boss will handle the negotiating process differently.

If you would like either of these benefits, simply sit down with your potential employer, and state these are the terms on which you will work. If they say yes, great. If they say no, try to convince them via some logical argument or your own personal charisma.

There may be many scenarios where it is impossible to reach a decision that is unilaterally favourable to you.

- Company policy does not allow certain allowances like working from home
- Person you are negotiating with does not have the power to grant these things
- Existing company infrastructure may prohibit the arrangement
- Person you are negotiating with might have a no negotiating on anything policy

Cheers